# Adjustment factor in logistic growth model of facebook-prophet

Tags: time-series, growth-model, logistic-curve, prophet

In the paper it emphasizes:

"When the rate k is adjusted, the offset parameter m
must also be adjusted to connect the endpoints of the segments. The correct adjustment
at changepoint j is easily computed as:"

$$\gamma_j = \left(s_j - m - \sum_{l<j}\gamma_l \right)\left(1 - \frac{k + \sum_{l<j} \delta_l}{k + \sum_{l \leq j} \delta_l} \right)$$

My understanding is, adjustment makes sure function is still continuous.

I have 2 questions regarding this model that are not explained in the paper:

How do we come up with the result function is not continuous without the adjustment factor, and how do we compute the adjustment factor?

Link to paper: https://peerj.com/preprints/3190/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked a friend, for anyone interested here how to come up with adjustment factor

[image: Computing adjustment factor]

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been accepted, but I just want to point out a more straightforward way to arrive there. The key to make sense of the formula is to recognize that both final growth rates and offsets are *cumulative sums* of respective adjustments, plus the initial rate and offset ($k$ and $m$). It's instantly clear from [the code](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/c00f6a2d72229faa6acee8292bc01e14f16f599c/python/stan/prophet.stan#L31).

They model logistic growth with saturation:
$$g(t) = \frac{C}{1+exp(-k(t-b))}$$
Denote $k_i$, $b_i$ and $s_i$ values of growth rates, offsets and starting times for segment $i$. We need this relation to hold:
$$k_i(s_i - b_i) = k_{i+1}(s_i - b_{i+1})$$
where $s_i$ is a changepoint.

Assuming we already know offsets up to the current point, we need to find next offset $\gamma_{i+1}$ such that
$$k_i(s_i - b_i) = (k_i + \delta_{i+1})(s_i - b_i - \gamma_{i+1})$$
Left hand side expression gets cancelled out so we're left with
$$\delta_{i+1}(s_i - b_i) = \gamma_{i+1}(k_i+\delta_{i+1})$$
$$\gamma_{i+1} = \frac{\delta_{i+1}(s_i - b_i)}{k_i+\delta_{i+1}}=\frac{(k_{i+1} - k_i)(t_i - b_i)}{k_{i+1}} = (1 - \frac{k_i}{k_{i+1}})(s_i - b_i)$$
which becomes the target expression after you expand rates and offsets as cumulative sums of adjustments.